# Is it possible to merge Google Places API with Google Geocoding API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am in the process of building a booking system and I'm wanting to do a lookup, based on a text field, that searches both businesses and addresses.

For example, a user is presented with an **Input Box** that asks them to enter a location. I want it to support **Businesses** and **Addresses**.

My current implementation uses the Geocoding web service, but it's unable to find businesses, so I need to bring in the Places API.

**I also need to find the distance between these places** using the Google Distance Matrix Web Service.

I thought I'd solved my problem by JUST using the Google Places API, but not all addresses are listed on it.

Any ideas / previous experience is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of these on the page, and place a condition for an unsuccessful search on one (i.e. missing or empty variable) to trigger the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with this approach is that Places API will sometimes return 1 result (a successful search), whilst geocode would potentially return 5 results (including the location that Places API provided). The problem here is that I'm unable to merge the results together because there would be duplicates.

Comment: would it be possible to try places first, and if there was no suitable response trigger geocode? I also thought you could limit the geocode responses (though the 1st may not be the correct out of 5)..

Comment: Yeah, it's a horrible result though because the user process will be: Input locations -> Choose the Place (If there are multiple).. But then it comes to another problem: What if the location isn't in the places list, I'd need to add another link below that saying 'Address search'. This is a very complex problem, I'm going to go and work it out. Thanks for your input buddy.